# What decides/controls number of returned records from Azure Table's ExecuteQuerySegmented(Async)'s?

Tags: .net, azure, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

What are the factors deciding how many records [ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable.executequerysegmentedasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_CloudTable_ExecuteQuerySegmentedAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_TableQuery_Microsoft_Azure_Cosmos_Table_TableContinuationToken_) returns?

My scenario is that the number of returned records used to be ~500 and now it's ~35.

---

EDIT

My code is:

```cs
TableContinuationToken token = null;
do
{
    TableQuerySegment<X> queryResult = table.ExecuteQuerySegmented(query, token);

    if (queryResult.Any())
    {
        OnDataReceived(queryResult);
    }
    token = queryResult.ContinuationToken;
} while (token != null);
```

`queryResult.Count()` is reliably ~35.

The query is generated in the following way:

```
private static TableQuery<X> GetQuery(string partitionKey, string startStr, string endStr)
{
    // Create filter for greater than start and less than end
    var startEpochQuery = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.GreaterThanOrEqual, startStr);
    var endEpochQuery = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("RowKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, endStr;
    var epochQuery = TableQuery.CombineFilters(startEpochQuery, TableOperators.And, endEpochQuery);
    
    // Query for partition key
    var partitionQuery = TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, partitionKey);
    
    // Combining the queries
    var combined = TableQuery.CombineFilters(partitionQuery, TableOperators.And, epochQuery);
    return new TableQuery<X>().Where(combined);
}
```

This results in `query.FilterString` being `(PartitionKey eq 'key_here') and ((RowKey ge '1596240000') and (RowKey le '1612915200'))`

Comment: are you sure no data are deleted previously, or are you querying the same data with same filter?

Comment: No data deletions: it's a store no data is ever deleted from.  Filter is not modified between calls.

Answer (score 0):

The size of the return record seems to affect the number of returned records.

When selecting a very small column the query result contains 1000 records, and as the payload grows the number of records drops.

Experimenting with [TableRequestOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.tablerequestoptions?view=azure-dotnet) settings, I was not able to affect how much is returned in a single fetch.